# trying to create ImageView in Java NOT xml but getting null point excptions

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, imageview

This is largely based on a code I grabbed from another site - it keeps throwing up null point exceptions. I've been told by another user here it is because I did not call for the ImageView from xml, so it's null when I try to use it - however this whole code seems to set the imageview up in java only - thinking I am missing something simple and don't have to add an xml layout to this. This is the complete code including a neat reflection effect which this imageview is trying to incorporate.

- is the issue right up front in the way I'm setting up the ImageView?
- or is the issue with what  getReflection  is returning?
- or is the issue with what I'm passing on to the getReflection method?
- or something else?

```
public class TileSet2 extends Activity  {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.announcementbc); 

        //Create an Image view and add our bitmap with reflection to it
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(getRefelection(originalImage));

        //Add the image to a linear layout and display it
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

         // set LinearLayout as ContentView
         setContentView(linLayout);



            }

    private Bitmap getRefelection(Bitmap originalImage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //The gap we want between the reflection and the original image
           final int reflectionGap = 4;




           int width = originalImage.getWidth();
           int height = originalImage.getHeight();


           //This will not scale but will flip on the Y axis
           Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
           matrix.preScale(1, -1);

           //Create a Bitmap with the flip matix applied to it.
           //We only want the bottom half of the image
           Bitmap reflectionImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage, 0, height/2, width, height/2, matrix, false);


           //Create a new bitmap with same width but taller to fit reflection
           Bitmap bitmapWithReflection = Bitmap.createBitmap(width
             , (height + height/2), Config.ARGB_8888);

          //Create a new Canvas with the bitmap that's big enough for
          //the image plus gap plus reflection
          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithReflection);

          //Draw in the original image
          canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, null);

          //Draw in the gap
          Paint deafaultPaint = new Paint();
          canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, height + reflectionGap, deafaultPaint);

          //Draw in the reflection
          canvas.drawBitmap(reflectionImage,0, height + reflectionGap, null);

          //Create a shader that is a linear gradient that covers the reflection
          Paint paint = new Paint();
          LinearGradient shader = new LinearGradient(0, originalImage.getHeight(), 0,
            bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, 0x70ffffff, 0x00ffffff,
            TileMode.CLAMP);

          //Set the paint to use this shader (linear gradient)
          paint.setShader(shader);

          //Set the Transfer mode to be porter duff and destination in
          paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

          //Draw a rectangle using the paint with our linear gradient
          canvas.drawRect(0, height, width, bitmapWithReflection.getHeight() + reflectionGap, paint);
          reflectionImage.recycle(); 




          return bitmapWithReflection;
    }


}
```

Comment: At which line are you getting NPE. Post the stacktrace

Comment: Exception details and stacktrace are in your LogCat.  Add them to your post.

Comment: I can't figure out the line from the logcat - have been looking for that before to narrow it down.

Comment: here is the logcat...

Comment: 06-14 22:15:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 22:15:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): Process: kronhelm.nordheim.loremaster, PID: 1225
06-14 22:15:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kronhelm.nordheim.loremaster/kronhelm.nordheim.loremaster.TileSet2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-14 22:15:06.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1225):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)

Comment: if it's 2121 - I don't know what that is referring to and how to find it... there are a few more statements below which I can append if anyone thinks it would help